# R Error in correlation test. 'x' must be a numeric vector

Tags: r, correlation, pearson

I know that this question has been asked before but not in the context i am asking it now.

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
      year    Units   
1 2005-2007   0.082 
2 2008-2010   0.411 
3 2011-2013   1.258
```

my simple code looks like this

```
Year = mydata$year
Units = mydata$Units
cor.test(mydataRyear, mydata$Units, type=pearson)
```

when i run the code i get the error

```
Error in cor.test.default(mydata$year, mydata$Units, type = pearson) : 'x' must be a numeric vector
```

your comments and suggestions are highly welcomed

Comment: `year` is not a numeric value - it will be either a character string or a factor.  Check with `str(mydata)`.  You could turn it into a numeric value by e.g. `as.numeric(substr(mydata$year,1,4))` or by using the factor levels `as.numeric(as.factor(mydata$year))` - although check the ordering makes sense if you use the latter.

Comment: Thanks the second suggestion solved the error @AndrewGustar

Answer (score 2):

`year` is not a numeric value - it will be either a character string or a factor. Check with `str(mydata)`.

You could turn it into a numeric value by e.g. `as.numeric(substr(mydata$year,1,4))` or by using the factor levels `as.numeric(as.factor(mydata$year))` - although check the ordering makes sense if you use the latter.